# Understanding compose in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm a bit confused on the following Ramda code I was playing around with in the REPL. I'm pretty new to functional  programming, and I'm trying to understand why `result2` and `result4` don't work. Here's my logic: `h = compose(f,g)` should behave the same as `h=f(g(x))` but it doesn't seem like I'm understanding correctly.

```js
const objs = [{test: 3, name: "name1"}, {test: 4, name: "name2"}]
const myPath = R.pathEq(["test"])
// works fine
const result1 = R.compose(R.filter,myPath)(3)(objs)
// doesn't work!
const result2 = R.compose(R.filter,myPath(3))(objs)

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);

// works fine as in result1
const result3 = R.compose(R.filter,R.pathEq)(["test"],3)(objs);
// throws exception!
const result4 = R.compose(R.filter,R.pathEq)(["test"])(3)(objs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: `result2` requires second argument for the curried function function `const result2 = R.compose(R.filter,myPath(3))()(objs)`

Comment: `result4` wouldn't work as `R.pathEq` requires two parameters, by the time you pass the second argument, curried function of `R.pathEq` is already passed on to filter which then takes the second argument as its own, rendering the third argument vague

Comment: @shrys So I think I then misunderstood the fact that `compose` doesn't auto-curry, which means `compose(x,y,z)(q)(p) == x(y(z(q)))(p)` as opposed to `x(y(z(q,p)))`, right?

Comment: yes exactly the point I tried to make :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compose function accepts `n` parameters, and pass it to the 1st function, the result of the 1st function (which can be a function) is passed to the 2nd function (which should accept only a single param). The 2nd function is invoked with that param, and the result can be a function as well.

In your code, the result of compose (before applying the `objs`) should be equal to `filter(R.pathEq(["test"], 3))`. The function would then be applied to `objs`.

---

**Case 1** - `R.compose(R.filter,myPath)(3)`

The `myPath` contains receives 3, and we get `R.pathEq(["test"], 3)` that is passed to `R.filter` to become the `filter(R.pathEq(["test"], 3))` function.

---

**Case 2** - `R.compose(R.filter,myPath(3))(objs)`

Calling `myPath(3)` is like setting `R.pathEq(["test"], 3)` directly. Now `objs` is passed to it, and the result is `false`. The `false` is passed to filter, which expects two params, and returns the partialy applied function (btw - since the predicate is `false` would fail).

---

**Case 3** - `R.compose(R.filter,R.pathEq)(["test"],3)(objs)`

The `(["test"],3)` is passed to `R.pathEq`, which results in `R.pathEq(["test"],3)` which is passed to filter, and you get the same function as case 1, which is applied to `objs`.

---

**Case 4** - `R.compose(R.filter,R.pathEq)(["test"])(3)(objs);`

The `["test"]` is passed to `R.pathEq`, which returns a function, which is passed to `R.filter()`, which returns a function. However, the function now gets the number `3`. Filter `3` returns an empty array, which is called on `objs`, and since an array is not a function, you get the error message.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the detailed explanation. To follow up then, I see that the results of `compose` are not auto-curried, which seems to align with what you're saying here. So then am I correct in saying that once `compose` is called with the first argument (say `h = compose(x,y,z)(q)`) then `h` takes on the value that is returned by `x(y(z(q)))`? So `h(p) == x(y(z(q)))(p)`. This is as opposed to `compose(x,y,z)(q)(p) == x(y(z(q,p)))` as I originally thought.

Comment: Indeed - `h(p) == x(y(z(q)))(p)` is correct. btw - The [docs for compose](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) state "Note: The result of compose is not automatically curried."

Comment: Ramda did at one point experiment with currying the output of `compose`, but it caused some real problems as described in https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1318 and https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1391.